# PHP Array to JSON with json_encode didnt work

Tags: php, json, slim, php-7

but could not find a solution.

so I have an Array that looks like this:

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 1
        [Vorname] => Fisrtname
        [Nachname] => Lastname
        [Geburtsdatum] => 1990-01-01
        [Email] => test@testmail.com
        [Telefon] => 0511123123
    ))
```

I want to convert it to JSON and use it as response with Slim.

The problem ist, that echo json_encode(); and return $response->withJson(); returns nothing.

As I said, I serached a lot and this this two ways was all I could find. Maybe you know why this didn't work.

Comment: whats the exact code you are using?

Comment: `json_last_error_msg()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix thanks for this tipp. I got this message: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Comment: Loop through array and fix it, `$item = mb_convert_encoding($item, "UTF-8", "UTF-8")`

Comment: We cannot say what ` $response->withJson();` is or does, since you did not tell us. But we certainly can say that `json_encode()` _does_ work when called with an array as argument.

Comment: Not with malformed UTF-8 it doesn't.

Comment: Its solved. Thanks to @ArtisticPhoenix.

Comment: That's because I got them skillz, lol

Comment: @arkascha $response->withJson is the default way to retrun Json with the Slim Framework. Its based on json_encode so I think the solution is the same.

Comment: If the issue really are issues with the character encoding then maybe you should fix the real cause, not the symptom...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RE: `json_last_error_msg()`

> Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

It's a common issue.

```
function utf8convert($mixed, $key = null)
{
    if (is_array($mixed)) {
        foreach ($mixed as $key => $value) {
            $mixed[$key] = utf8convert($value, $key); //recursive
        }
    } elseif (is_string($mixed)) {
        $fixed = mb_convert_encoding($mixed, "UTF-8", "UTF-8");
        return $fixed;
    }
    return $mixed;
}
```

It's almost like I just copied this code from something I wrote before ... lol ... this give me lot of headaches in the past. So, been there done that.

Comment: had to remove `$this->` as this was from a class I use for Json Encoding that does some automatic error resolution things, so I functionized it for you.

Comment: I used PDO to get the Array. So an other way is this : 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname . ";charset=utf8"

Comment: I tried that, I forget why I commented it out in the original one though ... lol.  So I can't remember why now, but I'm sure I had a reason.  See `//$fixed = utf8_encode();`  Maybe it was just faster, we do billions of rows of data so I always compare speeds.  Honestly I don't remember...

Comment: Maybe it was `Windows-1252` which `mb_` does convert... `Please note that utf8_encode only converts a string encoded in ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8`  In any case I tried it and decided not to use it...

Comment: @Adrian - that would be the preferred way if its a database source, in my case it's CSV files, that get put in a queuing system as JSON.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$arr=[
  [
    'ID'           => 1,
    'Vorname'      => 'Fisrtname',
    'Nachname'     => 'Lastname',
    'Geburtsdatum' => '1990-01-01',
    'Email'        => 'test@testmail.com',
    'Telefon'      => '0511123123'
  ]
];
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```